# GSON throwing "Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT"?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, gson, deserialization

The code throwing the exeption:

```
            String inputString = readWithScannerGson("outputGson.txt");
            Type outputListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<CPU>>(){}.getType();
            List<CPU> outputList = new Gson().fromJson(inputString, outputListType);
```

The txt file:

{
"name": "CPU.1",
"speed": 2.4,
"ram": 8.0,
"cache": 2.2
}{
"name": "CPU.2",
"speed": 2.0,
"ram": 16.0,
"cache": 4.0
}{
"name": "CPU.3",
"speed": 1.6,
"ram": 4.0,
"cache": 1.3
}

The code creating the txt:

```
public void serializeCpu(String filename) throws IOException {

    Writer writer = new FileWriter(filename);
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

    for (CPU c: list)
    {
        gson.toJson(c, writer);
    }

    writer.close();
}
```

Error:
"main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

I can't deserialize the output.txt to the an ArrayList

Comment: Your json file should contain json array to be able to be serialized to a list, like: [{"name":"intel 666"}...]

Answer (score 0):

if that is the json content of the file, it is invalid. The items should be declared as part of a list and separated by comma:

```
[{ "name": "CPU.1", "speed": 2.4, "ram": 8.0, "cache": 2.2 }, { "name": "CPU.2", "speed": 2.0, "ram": 16.0, "cache": 4.0 }, { "name": "CPU.3", "speed": 1.6, "ram": 4.0, "cache": 1.3 }]
```

Comment: I used also used GSON to create that file though, that's the code of the serialize Method:

    public void serializeCpu(String filename) throws IOException {

        Writer writer = new FileWriter(filename);
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

        for (CPU c: list)
        {
            gson.toJson(c, writer);
        }

        writer.close();
    }

Comment: instead of converitng each item to json and writing them one by one to the list, you should use gson to covert the whole list to json. `gson.toJson(list, writer)`