# Convert a Json file to a class objects but it's in a weird format

Tags: java, json, gson

Hello so this is my code:

```
public class Fencers{
    private String name,nation;
    private int id;

    public Fencers(String name, String nation,int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.nation = nation;
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return
                id+" "+name+" "+nation+"\n";
    }
}
```

and this is the main :

```
class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
         String json = "{\"name\":\"m\",\"nation\":\"egy\",\"id\":100}{\"name\":\"342\",\"nation\":\"egy\",\"id\":120}"
    }
}
```

I want to turn `json` to a class object but it gives me errors because it's in the weird format
what to do :palmface:

Comment: that String is not going to fly: you need to escape the quotation marks: `"{\"name\":\"m\",\"nation\":\"egy\",\"id\":100}{\"name\":\"342\",\"nation\":\"egy\",\"id\":120}"`

Comment: yes forgot to add that thanks

Comment: not only this, but that does not look like a valid json. By look,s I believe it should be an array of objects. Very similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75776996/gson-throwing-expected-begin-array-but-was-begin-object/75777042?noredirect=1#comment133672597_75777042

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are two issues here:

1. How should the conversion be done from json to java object? For example, using jackson (ObjectMapper)?
2. The json in the example is not valid:

```
{"name":"m","nation":"egy","id":100}{"name":"342","nation":"egy","id":120}
```

So before it can be converted from json to a java object, it has to be valid json.

Why the weird format? Can it be fixed at the source? If yes, (2) is solved, get valid json from wherever it has to be read from. If not, it has to be converted into valid json by your program first before deserializing the json into a java object with a library such as jackson.

If it's up to your program to convert the input into valid json before deserializing, assuming that all records have the format given in the example, and assuming that the key/value pairs won't contain parentheses or brackets, a really quick fix is a helper method, something like:

```
static String toValidJson(String in) {
    return "[" + in.replace("}{", "},{") + "]";
}
```

The idea here is to put a comma between objects and close the whole thing in an array. Then it can be deserialized as appropriate into an array, list, etc.

**Edit**

The Gson library is being used for parsing, so putting it all together, it should look something like:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // raw data
        String raw = "{\"name\":\"m\",\"nation\":\"egy\",\"id\":100}{\"name\":\"342\",\"nation\":\"egy\",\"id\":120}";

        // valid json
        String json = toValidJson(raw);

        // parse it
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Fencers[] fencers = gson.fromJson(json, Fencers[].class);

        // do something with the array of fencers
        for (Fencer f : fencers) {
            // ...
        }
    }

    static String toValidJson(String in) {
        return "[" + in.replace("}{", "},{") + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: or I can simply do that if I add them in a Array or a list and then load it to json but that is not in my hands sadly here I am just trying to convert this "json file" to a class objects

Comment: @MoustafaAmr so a little helper method to put the input in the correct format is all that is needed, then it can be deserialized by whatever library you're using.

Comment: Oh so I can edit json as much as I want to be in the correct format?

Comment: Sure, why not? look at it as a process. What needs to be done to get the raw text in a format that a json parser can understand? The parentheses `}{` need to have a comma between them to separate one object from another and the whole thing is an array of objects so it has to have `[` at the beginning and `]` at the end. Once that's been taken care of, the valid json can be given to a parser as input.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot. One last thing though how to convert the new correct format json file to class objects I know it's with the method .fromJson() I am just missing something can you please help

Comment: can you post more code? Which parser / library are you using?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry totally forgot to send that. I use Gson Library

Comment: ```com.google.gson.Gson;```

Comment: a file named ```file.json``` has this in it after correction [
  {
    "name":"m",
    "nation":"egy",
    "id":100},
  {
    "name":"342",
    "nation":"egy",
    "id":120
  }
]

Answer (score 1):

Your String is not going to work:

```java
String json = "{"name":"m","nation":"egy","id":100},"name":"342","nation":"egy","id":120}"
```

should be

```java
String json = "{\"name\":\"m\",\"nation\":\"egy\",\"id\":100}";
```

note that if you want an list of objects the json notation is not

```json
{"name":"m","nation":"egy","id":100}{"name":"342","nation":"egy","id":120}
```

but

```json
[{"name":"m","nation":"egy","id":100},{"name":"342","nation":"egy","id":120}]
```

In which case you should be writing:

```java
String json = "[{\"name\":\"m\",\"nation\":\"egy\",\"id\":100},{\"name\":\"342\",\"nation\":\"egy\",\"id\":120}]";
```

Comment: Yes forgot to edit the first part I can also load the data in an Array or a list to json but I can't change the data sadly I just need a way to turn it as it is to some class objects